# /dev/ttyUSB0 is available but after try to call it's gone

Tags: ubuntu, tty, ttyusb

If I connect my ESP32 to my Ubuntu ( 22.04 ) by USB it is available in `/dev/ttyUSB0`. If I run a call - for example `sudo ampy --port /dev/ttyUSB0 ls` the error message apears

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ampy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1656, in invoke
    super().invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ampy/cli.py", line 99, in cli
    _board = pyboard.Pyboard(port, baudrate=baud, rawdelay=delay)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ampy/pyboard.py", line 147, in __init__
    raise PyboardError('failed to access ' + device)
ampy.pyboard.PyboardError: failed to access /dev/ttyUSB0
```

On Ubuntu 20.04 this works very well, without any problem.  But since the upgrade, this issue is thrown.

Is there something to change on my Ubuntu settings?
The User has the following groups : `adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev render lpadmin lxd sambashare docker`

This is the output of `ls`. I add two comments to describe the workflow:

```
# Plug in the ESP32
michael@michael-Laptop:~$ ls /dev/tty*
/dev/tty    /dev/tty14  /dev/tty20  /dev/tty27  /dev/tty33  /dev/tty4   /dev/tty46  /dev/tty52  /dev/tty59  /dev/tty8       /dev/ttyS12  /dev/ttyS19  /dev/ttyS25  /dev/ttyS31  /dev/ttyUSB0
/dev/tty0   /dev/tty15  /dev/tty21  /dev/tty28  /dev/tty34  /dev/tty40  /dev/tty47  /dev/tty53  /dev/tty6   /dev/tty9       /dev/ttyS13  /dev/ttyS2   /dev/ttyS26  /dev/ttyS4
/dev/tty1   /dev/tty16  /dev/tty22  /dev/tty29  /dev/tty35  /dev/tty41  /dev/tty48  /dev/tty54  /dev/tty60  /dev/ttyprintk  /dev/ttyS14  /dev/ttyS20  /dev/ttyS27  /dev/ttyS5
/dev/tty10  /dev/tty17  /dev/tty23  /dev/tty3   /dev/tty36  /dev/tty42  /dev/tty49  /dev/tty55  /dev/tty61  /dev/ttyS0      /dev/ttyS15  /dev/ttyS21  /dev/ttyS28  /dev/ttyS6
/dev/tty11  /dev/tty18  /dev/tty24  /dev/tty30  /dev/tty37  /dev/tty43  /dev/tty5   /dev/tty56  /dev/tty62  /dev/ttyS1      /dev/ttyS16  /dev/ttyS22  /dev/ttyS29  /dev/ttyS7
/dev/tty12  /dev/tty19  /dev/tty25  /dev/tty31  /dev/tty38  /dev/tty44  /dev/tty50  /dev/tty57  /dev/tty63  /dev/ttyS10     /dev/ttyS17  /dev/ttyS23  /dev/ttyS3   /dev/ttyS8
/dev/tty13  /dev/tty2   /dev/tty26  /dev/tty32  /dev/tty39  /dev/tty45  /dev/tty51  /dev/tty58  /dev/tty7   /dev/ttyS11     /dev/ttyS18  /dev/ttyS24  /dev/ttyS30  /dev/ttyS9

michael@michael-Laptop:~$ ls /dev/tty*
/dev/tty    /dev/tty14  /dev/tty20  /dev/tty27  /dev/tty33  /dev/tty4   /dev/tty46  /dev/tty52  /dev/tty59  /dev/tty8       /dev/ttyS12  /dev/ttyS19  /dev/ttyS25  /dev/ttyS31
/dev/tty0   /dev/tty15  /dev/tty21  /dev/tty28  /dev/tty34  /dev/tty40  /dev/tty47  /dev/tty53  /dev/tty6   /dev/tty9       /dev/ttyS13  /dev/ttyS2   /dev/ttyS26  /dev/ttyS4
/dev/tty1   /dev/tty16  /dev/tty22  /dev/tty29  /dev/tty35  /dev/tty41  /dev/tty48  /dev/tty54  /dev/tty60  /dev/ttyprintk  /dev/ttyS14  /dev/ttyS20  /dev/ttyS27  /dev/ttyS5
/dev/tty10  /dev/tty17  /dev/tty23  /dev/tty3   /dev/tty36  /dev/tty42  /dev/tty49  /dev/tty55  /dev/tty61  /dev/ttyS0      /dev/ttyS15  /dev/ttyS21  /dev/ttyS28  /dev/ttyS6
/dev/tty11  /dev/tty18  /dev/tty24  /dev/tty30  /dev/tty37  /dev/tty43  /dev/tty5   /dev/tty56  /dev/tty62  /dev/ttyS1      /dev/ttyS16  /dev/ttyS22  /dev/ttyS29  /dev/ttyS7
/dev/tty12  /dev/tty19  /dev/tty25  /dev/tty31  /dev/tty38  /dev/tty44  /dev/tty50  /dev/tty57  /dev/tty63  /dev/ttyS10     /dev/ttyS17  /dev/ttyS23  /dev/ttyS3   /dev/ttyS8
/dev/tty13  /dev/tty2   /dev/tty26  /dev/tty32  /dev/tty39  /dev/tty45  /dev/tty51  /dev/tty58  /dev/tty7   /dev/ttyS11     /dev/ttyS18  /dev/ttyS24  /dev/ttyS30  /dev/ttyS9

# Plugout and plugin the ESP32
michael@michael-Laptop:~$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Mär 19 06:52 /dev/ttyUSB0

michael@michael-Laptop:~$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
ls: Zugriff auf '/dev/ttyUSB0' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

michael@michael-Laptop:~$ ls /dev/tty*
/dev/tty    /dev/tty14  /dev/tty20  /dev/tty27  /dev/tty33  /dev/tty4   /dev/tty46  /dev/tty52  /dev/tty59  /dev/tty8       /dev/ttyS12  /dev/ttyS19  /dev/ttyS25  /dev/ttyS31
/dev/tty0   /dev/tty15  /dev/tty21  /dev/tty28  /dev/tty34  /dev/tty40  /dev/tty47  /dev/tty53  /dev/tty6   /dev/tty9       /dev/ttyS13  /dev/ttyS2   /dev/ttyS26  /dev/ttyS4
/dev/tty1   /dev/tty16  /dev/tty22  /dev/tty29  /dev/tty35  /dev/tty41  /dev/tty48  /dev/tty54  /dev/tty60  /dev/ttyprintk  /dev/ttyS14  /dev/ttyS20  /dev/ttyS27  /dev/ttyS5
/dev/tty10  /dev/tty17  /dev/tty23  /dev/tty3   /dev/tty36  /dev/tty42  /dev/tty49  /dev/tty55  /dev/tty61  /dev/ttyS0      /dev/ttyS15  /dev/ttyS21  /dev/ttyS28  /dev/ttyS6
/dev/tty11  /dev/tty18  /dev/tty24  /dev/tty30  /dev/tty37  /dev/tty43  /dev/tty5   /dev/tty56  /dev/tty62  /dev/ttyS1      /dev/ttyS16  /dev/ttyS22  /dev/ttyS29  /dev/ttyS7
/dev/tty12  /dev/tty19  /dev/tty25  /dev/tty31  /dev/tty38  /dev/tty44  /dev/tty50  /dev/tty57  /dev/tty63  /dev/ttyS10     /dev/ttyS17  /dev/ttyS23  /dev/ttyS3   /dev/ttyS8
/dev/tty13  /dev/tty2   /dev/tty26  /dev/tty32  /dev/tty39  /dev/tty45  /dev/tty51  /dev/tty58  /dev/tty7   /dev/ttyS11     /dev/ttyS18  /dev/ttyS24  /dev/ttyS30  /dev/ttyS9
```

---- add `dmesg` output

Ok, this is absolute out of my knowledge... @dirkt  can you explane what the output say?

The following linkes are red:

and there are also a lot of red lines with this message:
`[   49.700482] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: DATA_ERROR 0000009c [] ch 2 [003fbf0000 systemd-logind[985]] subc 0 class 9197 mthd 0d78 data 00000004`

followed by this one  `[   49.832345] gnome-shell[1294]: segfault at 5596ea4d51c5 ip 00007f0afb25ceb7 sp 00007ffddb278bb8 error 4 in libgbm.so.1.0.0[7f0afb256000+7000]`

and last, i expect that this is focused on my ESP32 conection problem, because theres a lot of USB content
`[   83.658545] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of 10000000 FAULT at 002a00 [ !ENGINE ]`

This is the collection of the output:

```
[   49.700360] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: DATA_ERROR 0000009c [] ch 2 [003fbf0000 systemd-logind[985]] subc 0 class 9197 mthd 0d78 data 00000004
[   49.700447] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: DATA_ERROR 0000009c [] ch 2 [003fbf0000 systemd-logind[985]] subc 0 class 9197 mthd 0d78 data 00000004
[   49.700482] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: gr: DATA_ERROR 0000009c [] ch 2 [003fbf0000 systemd-logind[985]] subc 0 class 9197 mthd 0d78 data 00000004
[   49.832345] gnome-shell[1294]: segfault at 5596ea4d51c5 ip 00007f0afb25ceb7 sp 00007ffddb278bb8 error 4 in libgbm.so.1.0.0[7f0afb256000+7000]
[   49.832384] Code: 18 c3 90 f3 0f 1e fa 48 8b 07 ff a0 c0 00 00 00 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 48 8b 07 ff a0 a8 00 00 00 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 48 8b 07 <ff> a0 b0 00 00 00 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 48 8b 07 ff a0 b8 00 00 00
[   50.035755] rfkill: input handler enabled
[   52.299029] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   62.559834] systemd-journald[434]: File /var/log/journal/3f503f1656cc4352a889052ae6692375/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[   63.052568] rfkill: input handler enabled
[   65.125545] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   65.339576] audit: type=1400 audit(1647699924.695:85): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/15177/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3840 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
[   67.400897] audit: type=1326 audit(1647699926.753:86): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=? pid=3840 comm="snap-store" exe="/snap/snap-store/558/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7f85943b876d code=0x50000
[   68.076416] audit: type=1400 audit(1647699927.429:87): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/run/user/1000/at-spi/bus" pid=3840 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   69.760939] audit: type=1107 audit(1647699929.112:88): pid=954 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=3840 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=970 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[   69.760961] audit: type=1420 audit(1647699929.112:89): subj_apparmor=unconfined
[   69.761676] audit: type=1107 audit(1647699929.112:90): pid=954 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=3840 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=970 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[   69.761696] audit: type=1420 audit(1647699929.112:91): subj_apparmor=unconfined
[   69.788634] audit: type=1107 audit(1647699929.140:92): pid=954 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=3840 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=970 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[   69.788670] audit: type=1420 audit(1647699929.140:93): subj_apparmor=unconfined
[   69.789381] audit: type=1107 audit(1647699929.140:94): pid=954 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.7" pid=3840 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=970 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[   70.362315] kauditd_printk_skb: 1 callbacks suppressed
[   70.362322] audit: type=1400 audit(1647699929.717:96): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/PackageKit/Vendor.conf" pid=3840 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[   83.651321] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[   83.658545] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of 10000000 FAULT at 002a00 [ !ENGINE ]
[  180.681078] usb 2-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[  180.828308] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  180.828315] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  180.828317] usb 2-1.4: Product: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[  180.828319] usb 2-1.4: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[  180.828320] usb 2-1.4: SerialNumber: 0001
[  180.855749] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[  180.855768] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[  180.859082] usbcore: registered new interface driver cp210x
[  180.859114] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for cp210x
[  180.859154] cp210x 2-1.4:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[  180.860044] usb 2-1.4: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  180.914950] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input23
[  181.433918] input: BRLTTY 6.4 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input24
[  182.932720] usb 2-1.4: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by cp210x while 'brltty' sets config #1
[  182.933473] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[  182.933505] cp210x 2-1.4:1.0: device disconnected
[  249.064792] usb 2-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  252.466888] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  252.665144] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  252.665164] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  252.665170] usb 3-2: Product: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[  252.665175] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[  252.665180] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 0001
[  252.683233] cp210x 3-2:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[  252.689407] usb 3-2: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  268.444106] usb 3-2: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by cp210x while 'brltty' sets config #1
[  268.447566] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[  268.447632] cp210x 3-2:1.0: device disconnected
[  355.671608] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
[  362.191120] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[  389.497934] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  392.335966] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  392.533200] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  392.533210] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  392.533214] usb 3-2: Product: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[  392.533218] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[  392.533221] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 0001
[  392.550293] cp210x 3-2:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[  392.556443] usb 3-2: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  410.282303] usb 3-2: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by cp210x while 'brltty' sets config #1
[  410.285810] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[  410.285877] cp210x 3-2:1.0: device disconnected
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0`.

Comment: Have a look at `dmesg` after you do the access, and see if there is an error that cause udev to remove the device. Or rename it. Or do something else unexpected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have the exact same issue with a USB→serial converter.

Worked fine on 20.04 (even 21.10), and with 22.04 I see the device appearing for a short time, then 1 or 2 seconds later, disappears.

dmesg output:

```
[ 2713.068159] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[ 2713.222910] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00
[ 2713.222922] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2713.222927] usb 1-2: Product: TTL232RG-VREG1V8
[ 2713.222931] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[ 2713.222934] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: FT08D7RY
[ 2713.228289] ftdi_sio 1-2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[ 2713.228361] usb 1-2: Detected FT232RL
[ 2713.229373] usb 1-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 2714.563520] usb 1-2: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ftdi_sio while 'brltty' sets config #1
[ 2714.564784] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 2714.564845] ftdi_sio 1-2:1.0: device disconnected
```

The culprit, if you look into the dmesg output is the 'brltty' daemon.

Somehow it is taking over the ftdi driver (I suppose). Looks like a regression based on what I found here from 2011 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/brltty/+bug/874181). Probably needs to be addressed, as braille access is likely key for accessibility features.

Anyhow, the fix for me was: `sudo apt remove brltty`,
and I can use minicom (my serial bridge of choice) again.

Comment: You nailed it.  Thank you.  Had the same problem upgrading from 18.04 to 22.04.  What was most frustrating for me was that my ttyUSB task is running as a service.  I could plainly see it running for about half a second during boot before getting killed.